# implications of altering the table structure without disabling the table in HBASE

Tags: hbase

Can anyone please tell me the possible implications that may affect the table structure if use "alter" command without disabling the table first?
 
To my knowledge disabling a table means closing all the connections to the table. What peculiarities may take place if I use alter without disabling the table?
I am learning HBase
Please help!!
            
            
            Thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on HBase configuration. If parameter "hbase.online.schema.update.enable" set to true, you can do online updates table schema, otherwise you can't. In newest HBase versions this parameter turned on by default. Note, that some changes in configuration, like the changes of compression codec or block size, will not affect old HFiles. Only after compaction a new parameter will be applied to old data involved in this compaction.

Comment: Look, Alex, I tried doing the same at my end. What did I exactly do? I altered the name of a column family and did not  disable the table prior to it. Now the changes were automatically committed to the existing table. When I desctibed the table schema I am able to see the old column family as well as the new one that I had altered recently. What could be the reason behind this? Was it due to not disabling the table prior to alteration of the table properties? Hope I am able to communicate my question effectively :)

Comment: Unfortunately you can't rename column family via shell, because column family name stored with data. To "rename" column family this you need create a new column family with new name and copy data to it, then delete old.

Comment: Yes that's the answer that I was looking for!! Hey Alex nice meeting ya! Thanks :)